# Debugging and Compilation of a file with class dependency on VS Code

Tags: c++, class, debugging, linked-list, compilation

How do I debug my code that has implementation of a class on VSCode?
Is there any other way to compile and debug other than the method shown below?
Main file code below.

```
#include<iostream>
#include "Node.h"
using namespace std;
int main(){
    Node test;
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int a[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>a[i];
        test.append(&test.head,a[i]);
    }  
    test.printList(test.head);
    test.insertAfter(test.head->next->next,9); 
    test.printList(test.head);

}
```

Class implementation file below

```
#include<iostream>
#include "Node.h"
using namespace std;

Node::Node(){
    head=NULL;
}

void Node::append(Node** head_ref,int newData){
    Node* newNode= new Node;
    newNode->data=newData;
    if(*head_ref==NULL){
        newNode->prev=NULL;
        newNode->next=NULL;
        *head_ref=newNode;
        return;
    }
    Node *n=*head_ref;
    while(n->next!=NULL)
        n=n->next;
    newNode->next=n->next;
    newNode->prev=n;
    n->next=newNode;

}
void Node::insertAfter(Node* prev_node,int newData){
    Node* newNode= new Node;
    newNode->data=newData;
    prev_node->next->prev=newNode;
    newNode->next=prev_node->next;
    newNode->prev=prev_node;
    prev_node->next=newNode;

}


void Node::printList(Node*n){
    if(n==NULL)
        return;
    while(n!=NULL){
        cout<<n->data<<" ";
        n=n->next;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

Node* Node::findTail(Node** head_ref){
    Node* n= *head_ref;
    while(n->next!=NULL)
        n=n->next;
    return(n);
}
```

How I compile and run my code.Any better method to compile and run or debug on VS Code for such circumstances?

```
g++ main.cpp Node.cpp
```

Comment: I assume you've read the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp)?

Comment: Well at the very least, if you are going to debug your code, you need the `-g` option.